# Concerning $\mathbb{C}(s_1,s_2,w)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$, where $s_1,s_2$ are symmetric, $w$ is not symmetric

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, field-theory, symmetric-polynomials

Let $s_1,s_2, w \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]-\mathbb{C}$. Let $\alpha$ be the following involution,
$\alpha: (x,y) \mapsto (y,x)$.

Assume that:

**(1)** Each of $s_1,s_2$ is symmetric w.r.t. $\alpha$.

**(2)** $w$ is *not* symmetric w.r.t. $\alpha$.

**(3)** $\mathbb{C}(s_1,s_2,w)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$.
(The notation is of fields of fractions).

I think that the following claim is true, but not sure how to prove it; any help in proving it is welcome!

> **Claim:**
> (At least) one of the following happens:
>
> - (At least) one of $\{s_1,s_2\}$ belongs to $\{\lambda(x+y),\mu xy\}_{\lambda,\mu \in \mathbb{C}}$.
> - $w=\lambda y+as_1+bs_2$ or $w=\mu x+cs_1+ds_2$, for some $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{C}$, $\lambda,\mu \in \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$.
> - $\mathbb{C}(s_1,s_2)=\mathbb{C}(x+y,xy)$ (thanks to Peter Wu's comments).

**Several ideas:**

**(i)** First, it is convenient to concentrate on the special case where $w=y$
(or $w=x$), so $\mathbb{C}(s_1,s_2,y)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$.
We need to show that $x \in \mathbb{C}(s_1,s_2)$.

**(ii)** Actually, I have listed several low degree symmetric elements $x+y,xy,x^2+y^2,x^2y+xy^2,x^3+y^3$ etc. and checked for each two chosen $s_1,s_2$ from that list when, together with $y$, the three generate $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$; always one of $s_1,s_2$ was $x+y$ or $xy$.

**(iii)** It is clear that if $s=x+y$ or $s_1=xy$, then regardless of what $s_2$ is,
we have $\mathbb{C}(s_1,s_2,y)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$.

**(iv)** $\mathbb{C}(s_1,s_2) \subseteq \mathbb{C}(x+y,xy) \subseteq \mathbb{C}(x,y)$.
Therefore, the degree of the field extension $\mathbb{C}(s_1,s_2) \subseteq \mathbb{C}(x,y)$ is a multiple of $2$.

**(v)** Probably, a proof for my above claim would involve arguments similar to the ones appearing in [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453393/if-mathbbcux-y-vx-y-fx-mathbbcx-y-for-every-fx-in-mathbb?noredirect=1&lq=1) answer.

**(vi)** It seems quite difficult for two arbitrary symmetric $s_1,s_2$ and one arbitrary non-symmetric $w$ to generate $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$, even when $w=y$! For example: $s_1=x^2+y^2,s_2=x^3+y^3,w=y$ generate $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$, but $s_1=x^2+y^2,s_2=x^4+y^4,w=y$ do not generate $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ it generates $\mathbb{C}(x^2,y)$.

Thank you very much!

Comment: For $s_1=x^2+y^2,s_2=x^3+y^3,w=y$, we have $\mathbb{C}(s_1,s_2,w)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$, but non of $\{s_1,s_2\}$ belongs to $\{\lambda(x+y),\mu xy\}_{\lambda,\mu \in \mathbb{C}}$, so I should edit my question.

Comment: $s_1=x^2+y^2,s_2=x^2y+xy^2,w=y$. $\mathbb{C}(s_1,s_2,w)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$.

Comment: If $s_1,s_2$ generate ring $R$, then $s_1,s_2+f(s_1)$ also generate $R$ for any polynomial $f$. So start from $s_1=xy,\,s_2=x+y,\,w=x+xy$, and use this to levitate degree of $s$

Comment: @PeterWu, thank you very much for your comment! Please, could you elaborate more?

Comment: Say here a explicit counterexample: $s_1=x+y+xy,\,s_2=x+y+s_1^2,\, w=x+(xy)^3$, btw, I found the automorphism of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is characterized explicitly, see here: https://www.mun.ca/aac/media/production/memorial/academic/faculty-of-science/mathematics-and-statistics/atlantic-algebra-centre/media-library/aacminicourses/Lecture_1(checked)_Automorphisms%20of%20C[x,y]_and_Rentscler.pdf

Comment: @PeterWu, thank you for your nice counterexample! and related paper. You can make your comment an answer. I wonder if any similar claim to my claim may hold?

Comment: In your nice counterexample to my claim: $\mathbb{C}(s_1,s_2)=\mathbb{C}(x+y,xy)$ (so $[\mathbb{C}(x,y) : \mathbb{C}(s_1,s_2)]=[\mathbb{C}(x,y) : \mathbb{C}(x+y,xy)]=2$). What if $\mathbb{C}(s_1,s_2) \subsetneq \mathbb{C}(x+y,xy)$? It seems to me that if $\mathbb{C}(s_1,s_2) \subsetneq \mathbb{C}(x+y,xy)$, then my claim is true.

Comment: Another variation is to assume that $w$ is skew-symmetric w.r.t. $\alpha$, for example $w=x-y$. Example: $s_1=x^2+y^2,s_2=x^2y+xy^2,w=x-y$, then $L:=\mathbb{C}(s_1,s_2,w)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$, since $xy,x+y,x-y \in L$.